# 2nd image appears as mirror image in IE--- CSS image FLIP transform- How to fix?

Tags: html, css

Im hoping someone can help me get my code to flip my second image properly (not mirror image) when viewed in IE. I think I have it working properly in the other browsers. 
My goal is to have picture #1 show, then upon button click show the picture #2.

The code also uses javascript + jquery but my knowledge currently is limited.
Can someone offer a solution via css that I can add or amend my code with to accomplish what I am trying to do? Thanks.

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zgn9kd0L/6/

HTML

```
<div id="block" class="block" onclick="changeClass()">
    <div class="front side">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/etY8veW.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="back side">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/DiSXWpR.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<button class="flip">Flip</button>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    /*perspective*/
    -webkit-perspective: 500;
    -moz-perspective: 500;
    -ms-perspective: 500;
    -o-perspective: 500;
    perspective: 500;
}

.block {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    /*transform-style*/
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    /*transition*/
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1.5s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1.5s;
    transition: transform 1.5s;
}

.rotated {
    /*transform*/
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.side {
    position: absolute;
    /*backface-visibility*/
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
}

.back {
    /*transform*/
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip {
    background: white;
    font-family: 'open sans';
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #5b5b5b;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IE10+ only has partial support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) for the property `transform-style: preserve-3d`. I assume that's why it wasn't working.

Here is a similar alternative that works in IE. [**(updated example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/z19upmfv/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="front side">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/etY8veW.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="back side">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/DiSXWpR.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** - vendor prefixes omitted. See the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/z19upmfv/).

```
.block {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 500;
}
.side {
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.side.rotated {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Josh that was a HUGE help. Your fiddle didn't include the js I had in there to make the pic clickable to flip and Im having a hard time with the js syntax to insert your new multiple class selector, .side.rotated to replace my old .rotated  
I don't know how to do that in javascipt. Please let me know if I have to ask a new question for this.

Comment: While the flip now works in IE, it appears to come with a caveat. On mobile (have only tested on ios7.1) the second image when flipped now flickers...where it didnt before...If you check my first fiddle and then the one above on mobile and flip the image, the second image is wonky. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Pure CSS Solutions here are few:

[**Create a CSS Flipping Animation**](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)

[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/darkwing/pen/bCali)

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="name">David Walsh</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="back-logo"></div>
      <div class="back-title">@davidwalshblog</div>
      <p>Mozilla Web Developer, MooTools & jQuery Consultant, MooTools Core Developer, Javascript Fanatic, CSS Tinkerer, PHP Hacker, and web lover.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;

    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

    .flip-container:hover .flipper,  
  .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 427px;
}

.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    background: url(http://davidwalsh.name/demo/dwflip.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
}

.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);

    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.front .name {
    font-size: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
    color: #f8f8f8;
    font-family: Courier;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.back-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 90px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 117px;
    background: url(http://davidwalsh.name/demo/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.back-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00304a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #acd7e5;
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.back p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I had looked at this code previously and am looking specifically to change pics back and forth upon button click.

Comment: If you goto demo page http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php there is option for flip using click(Toggle Flip (Horizontal).

Comment: @Jatin - The demo you provided does not work in Internet Explorer. The OP's request was for the image flip to work correctly in Internet Explorer. The code on the page that you refer to does work in Internet Explorer, but you should correct the code in your post as well.